# como hacer join con mysql + nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs

hice esta funcion para hacer join entre 2 tablas pero creo que no es la manera correcta

```
function insertarDatosToArchivos(){

objBD.query('SELECT ID_U from usuario', function(err, rows, fields) {
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        objBD.query('SELECT ID_L   from LETRA where rows[i].ID_U=LETRA.ID_U', function(err, rows, fields) {

        });
    };

});

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que es más simple si haces la consulta en una sola llamada a `mysql`. Algo así:

```
function insertarDatosToArchivos(){

    objBD.query('SELECT u.ID_U, l.ID_L from usuario u INNER JOIN LETRA l ON u.ID_U = l.ID_U', function(err, rows, fields) {
        //Tu código de lógica acá
    }});

};
```

De esta forma optimizas el número de llamadas a la base de datos y a su vez el tiempo de ejecución de tu función.

Comment: si serian 3 tablas?